# How are 16x16 PNG icons rendered from original SVG files?

Tags: svg, icons, antialiasing

When I open a Tango SVG icon file and export it (using Inkscape) to a 16x16 png, I get a rather blurry image. Instead, the "official" 16x16 render is extremely sharp. How did they do it? Did they pixel-paint the icons at small resolutions?

Compare [image: Gnome theme official rendering] and [image: My rendering] for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Gimp has a better scaling algorithm than Inkscape.

I Export from inkscape to 256x256 pixels and then scale to 16x16 in Gimp.